# Does Firefox for Android have trouble loading page before executing JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, html, firefox, viewport

I want to use `document.documentElement` to get the `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` of the loaded web page. I also want to use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>` to keep my viewport to scale on mobile devices. This approach works on Android Chrome, Opera, and Dolphin browsers, but not on Firefox. Firefox seems to be executing my JavaScript before the page is fully loaded. The meta tag has no effect, and `document.documentElement.clientWidth` returns 980, which I'm sure is a default value.

The hack I've been seeing online is to add a time delay before executing any JavaScript, which to me is a terrible solution. The page also renders correctly if I put an `alert("");` in my code, but this is sort of the same thing as the time delay and even more ridiculous as a work around.

In addition, the page seems to render differently (although still incorrectly in both cases) on first load and after page refresh. I'm sure Firefox is just caching some stuff like it does with scroll position, but please tell me there is a way to get my page to load correctly in Firefox for Android the first time without these stupid hacks.

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <script src="file_with_initialize_function_in_it.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>How to bake a cake with goat milk</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // alert("I don't like goat cake.");
            // The page works fine if I uncomment the above line.
            initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the file_with_initialize_function_in_it.js:

```
function initialize(){
    var output=document.createElement("p");
    output.id="output";// There is a css file that defines color for output
    output.style.top=document.documentElement.clientHeight*0.5+"px";
    document.body.appendChild(output);
}
```

I noticed that the meta tag works fine when I create the output

element in the html itself rather than using JS to create it and append it dynamically.

Comment: I realize I stupidly add a forward slash to close my meta tag: "<meta ... />", which is totally unnecessary, but I tested it with the forward slash removed and it works the same way.

Comment: What about using the `DOMContentLoaded` event to trigger your measurement when you know the page has been loaded?  That doesn't guarantee that all images have yet been loaded if the page is such that images affect its size.  You could wait for all images in the HTML to load with the `window` `load` event.

Comment: I tried     window.addEventListener("load",initialize); But that doesn't do the trick. I know the event fires because the initialize function is executed. I also tried document.addEventListener("readystatechange",initialize) and tested for "complete", but no luck.

Comment: If `window` `load` doesn't work, then your problem is not about timing because everything is loaded and laid out at the time of that event unless there is JS that is dynamically creating parts of the DOM and is still doing its thing after those events.  Apparently `.clientWidth` and `.clientHeight` just aren't giving you the values you want in Firefox.

Comment: That is one possibility and I can work around that with window.innerWidth, but my more pressing problem is that the meta tag does not work.

Comment: After looking into what you mentioned about updating the DOM with JS, I realized that the meta tag works fine when I don't change the style properties of the elements I am adding... I will update the question to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem with the meta tag by not adding elements to the DOM dynamically. I can still manipulate the `style` properties of these elements dynamically, but putting them right into the html rather than using `document.body.appendChild()` seems to allow the meta tag to do its thing and scale the mobile environment nicely.

However, the problem still remains with `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. Unless I include some sort of time delay or use an `alert("")`, `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` return default values of 980 and 480. This is strange to me because they are rendered correctly with the delay in place, but return default values otherwise even when calling them inside the callback function of a `"load"` event listener on the `window` or a `"readystatechange"` event listener on the `document`.

Comment: not only does `document.documentElement` return default dimensions, but so do `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.